# Retorna + valores da coluna corresponde com PHP e Mysql

Tags: php, html, css

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma tabela que recebe dados de um mysql que funciona corretamente. Porém ele não retorna os valor correspondente de uma coluna todos dentro de uma , Exemplo:

**Como fica:**

```
    PROFESSOR     |   ALUNOS

    CARLOS        |  LUIZ
    CARLOS        |  CAIO
    CARLOS        |  matheus
    CARLOS        |  ROBERTO


    JOSE         |  RODRIGO
    JOSE         |  LEANDRO
    JOSE         |  WAGNER
    JOSE         |  LUIZ


    ELDER         |  LUIZ
    ELDER         |  EDUARDO
    ELDER         |  VICTOR
    ELDER         |  RODRIGO
```

**Como eu gostaria que ficasse**

```
 PROFESSOR        |   ALUNOS


    CARLOS        |  LUIZ,caio,matheus,roberto


    JOSE          |  RODRIGO,LEANDRO,WAGNER,LUIZ


    ELDER         |  LUIZ,EDUARDO,VICTOR,RODRIGO
```

**Meu código**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-filters">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Professor</th>
            <th>Aluno</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>'
               foreach($analises as $key => $cada){

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $cada->['professor']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $cada->['aluno']; ?></td>                 
                </tr>;

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: posta a query que está sendo feita.

Comment: Já vou adiantar que você precisa conhecer a função [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) para achar a resposta que você quer. Mas como o Lucas já falou, você não postou o mais importante da sua pergunta, sua query.

Answer (score 1):

No meu entendimento você deveria ter duas consultas ao banco de dados. Uma só de professores onde você faz um `group by` de professores. Ao fazer o loop para percorrer os registros você faz outra consulta dentro do loop buscando os alunos correspondentes ao professor do laço, preenchendo outra tabela
Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<table>
  <?php
foreach ($listaProfessores as $key => $professor) {
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:solid 1px;border-collapse: collapse;"><?=$professor['professor'];?>:</td>
    <td>
      <table style="border:solid 1px;border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT aluno from aulas where professor = '{$professor['professor']}';";
        $resultado = $conexao->query($query);
        $listaAlunos = $resultado->fetchAll();
        foreach ($listaAlunos as $key => $aluno) {
        ?>
          <td>
            <?=$aluno['aluno'].' ';?>
          </td>
        <?php }?>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
}?>
</table>
```